# 投票ボタンのツールチップで表示される説明文が翻訳できない

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳

投票の UI 周りの string が未翻訳なので翻訳したいのですが、Traducir に string が登録されていません。登録していただけないでしょうか？

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

先ほど確認したところ、 https://ja.traducir.win でそれぞれ関連するStringsを見つけたので、翻訳案を反映しておきました。実際にサイトに反映されるまで少しお待ちください。

https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13776
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13759
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13772
https://ja.traducir.win/strings/13767

Comment: ちょうど string が更新される切れ目だったのですかね。ありがとうございます！

Comment: MSE では割と頻繁に追加依頼が出ているので、うっかり反映忘れのケースかもしれませんが…。関連の文字列で一つ traducir.win では見つからないものがあったので、こちらは transifex で反映しておきました。